# VBA in Excel ignores selections

Tags: excel, vba

When I run for example the following code, which I copied from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291308 (the first line anyway), the selection just doesn't work:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 4).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "test"
```

When I use`ActiveSheet.Cells(5,4).value = "test"` it does work.

edit: the result is it writes test in the cell I had selected before I pressed the button the code is attached to. Hence me claiming it ignores the select.

edit2: a bit of Excel code that runs on another computer doesn't run on this one due to Excel skipping the select part.

Comment: Works fine for me. When, and how, are you running this code? You know don't you that it only selects a single cell?

Comment: selecting a single cell is the point, yes ;) And I am running this when pressing a button!

Comment: .Select should work...however can you try .activate

Comment: I know it should work, that's why I'm so confused! Anyway, .activate unfortunatly doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you check that (a) your sheet is unlocked and (b) there is not any before_selection event in your spreadsheet, that could do funny things?

Comment: (a) not sure how to set a worksheet to locked, but I can type in it myself, the code still outputs test to the cell I had selected before I pressed the button, (b) it is an empty spreadsheet with only the button and that line of code.

Comment: I was thinking it could be some kind of setting somewhere, but I went by the entire options menu and I don't think there was anything unusual there

Comment: Now that is weird.. Check @gary's student's suggestion below, it's a good starting point.

Comment: Try placing activesheet .EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions just before you call select.. Does it work?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: And what kind of button are you using? ActiveX, Forms, Shape. What steps did you take to add the button?

Comment: it's activeX, I did nothing special, I click on the normal add a button stuff, dragged a button, double clicked with the desing thing and added the code, I am using excel 2010 profesional, or more specifically: `14.0.6129.5000 (32-bits)`

Comment: LOANNIS! that works! :D what does that do specifically? how can I fix this without having to use that line all the time? Also, could you make that an answer? then I can accept it as one!

Comment: It reverses the result of activesheet.enablesslection= xlNoSelection, which is triggered by something we don't know  (see @s nash's scenario below for example). What I suggest is a treatment, not a cure.. You still need to find what causes that, check your add-ins for example.. I'm sure some experts will have more ideas.

Comment: Doesn't solve your problem, whoever, wouldn't `ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 4).Value = "test"` be more effective in your case?

Comment: well yes, but this is just a test case ;) In a different, lengthier code that works now, I do need the selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment provided a workaround for your problem, I decided to do some more research to escalate it to an answer.

The [msdn website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214580%28v=office.11%29.aspx) mentions the following for the `.EnableSelection` property:

"This property takes effect only when the worksheet is protected: `xlNoSelection` prevents any selection on the sheet, `xlUnlockedCells` allows only those cells whose Locked property is False to be selected, and `xlNoRestrictions` allows any cell to be selected."

Since `ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions` worked in your sheet, there is nothing else to conclude other than that the sheet is protected. But *why* the worksheet is protected, that we cannot know, but most likely it is an Add-In that triggers some kind of protection, as @S Nash mentioned in his answer. (And of course I am open to listen to other opinions/suggestions).

You can try to remove add-ins (see [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-or-remove-add-ins-HP010342658.aspx#BMexceladdin)) and then restart excel and see if the problem persists (and if you can, please post back if it was finally an add-in that caused the problem, it is interesting for everyone!)

Comment: all of my add-ins are disabled, yet the problem persists, huge thank you for your workaround either way!

Comment: I did figure it out btw! Or partially I guess, I suspect that it has to do with the rights of this computer to the network drives, when I move the file to my desktop it will run fine without the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your two lines with these four lines:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 4).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "test"
MsgBox Selection.Address
MsgBox ActiveCell.Address
```

What do you see??

Comment: both of the msgboxes say: `$J$14`
Which was the cell I had selected at the time of hitting the button

Answer (score 0):

"edit2: a bit of excel code that runs fine on another computer also doesn't run on this one due to excel skippin the select part."

This is my strong guess:

There is an add-in in the Excel in this computer which cancels the selection.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 4).Select
```

otherwise

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 4).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "test"
```

Should always work.

Try to disable the excel Add-ins one by one to find the intruder.
I  know by expereince that many Excel addins, such as reuters or bloomberg links may interfere with the Excel Cell Select.

Comment: http://d3j5vwomefv46c.cloudfront.net/photos/large/803520439.png?1377518997

My version is in dutch, but I think you mean this list, which unfortunatly is empty :\

Comment: I can't read german but no , it's defintely not there. You have to open the Excel Addin window from the main Excel view, not the developers view.

Comment: What version of Excel you have? For Excel 2007 click on Office button on top left then "Excel options" then choose add-ins and click on GO

Comment: Found them! I'll have a look ;)

Comment: There is nothing strange there though I'm afraid, as well as nothing I can disable? They are all cathegorised under inactive, but I can't activate them either? Oh wait I found some I can change, but they're all off